# How to pass index of an array from one component to another in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I am using angular and I have an array in typescript file like this.

```
var channelArray = {"channel1", "channel2", "channel3"}
```

In my html I have code like

```
<div *ngFor="let val of channelArray">
            <de-series-prop></de-series-prop>
            </div>
```

How do I pass the index of the array to series-prop component. I need the index value to assign some values in series-prop component.

Comment: You mean a JS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ngFor exposes the **index** as a local variable.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html).

Comment: Thanks for this info.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let val of channelArray; let i = index">
  <de-series-prop [index]="i"></de-series-prop>
</div>
```

In your component:

```
@Input()
index: Number;
```